# In Angular version1 how do I test that my scope.$on listener is being called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

In Angular version1 how do I test that my scope.$on listener is being called?

**This is my code:**

```
$scope.$on("pagination:getCardExpandData", (event, cardObj) => $scope.loadLocationCardExpandedData(cardObj));
```

**This is my test:**

```
  it("should call loadLocationCardExpandedData function on emit", function () {
     scope.$emit('pagination:getCardExpandData', {});

     expect(scope.$on.calledWith("pagination:getCardExpandData", {})).toEqual(true);
     expect(scope.loadLocationCardExpandedData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**This is the error I get:**  Expected false to equal true.

I'm using karma runner with jasmine and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Do a $digest so angular knows to update.

```
scope.$emit('pagination:getCardExpandData', {});
scope.$digest();
```

Alternatively you could of listened in on a parent scope:

```
var called = false;
$rootScope.$on('pagination:getCardExpandData', function(){
    called = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that tomorrow and let you know

Answer (score 0):

**To get this to work i need to do this:**

```
scope.$emit('pagination:getTabPage', "next", function(){
        expect(scope.$on.calledWith("pagination:getTabPage", "next")).toEqual(true);
        expect(scope.loadLocationTab).toHaveBeenCalled();
     });
```